# Keep String property after inseriting to a list

Tags: string, list, prolog, swi-prolog

I´m doing a project where I need to recognize specific strings and add them to a list. Im using this method to insert them in a specific position:

```
insertAt(E,N,Xs,Ys) :-
   same_length([E|Xs],Ys),
   append(Before,Xs0,Xs),
   length(Before,N),
   append(Before,[E|Xs0],Ys)
```

The problem is that when I insert any String for example '4X',in my list appears 4X, as a number and a variable. How can i keep the single quotes after the insert? 
This is the line that gives me problems:

`insertAt('>500',0,ListA,ListB),writeln(ListB).`

When the list show in promt it looks like [>500],without the quotes.

Comment: I tried to convert it to String and get the same, also with double quotes.

Comment: Your problem isn't as you describe it. From what I see when I tried it, your logic is off. You need to give examples of input and expected output for a few different cases then we will have some idea of how the code is suppose to work.

Comment: I think the problem come from the 'write' method.
Check this two outputs:

insertAt('4X', 1, [1,2,3],Y), writeln(Y).

[1,4X,2,3]

Y = [1, '4X', 2, 3]

Is there a way to write while maintaing the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Simple example since you didn't indicate how you are creating 4X

```
test :-
    append(["4x"],[],New),
    write(New).
```

Example run:

```
?- test.
[4x]
true.
```

---

After updates in comments.

> Is there a way to write while maintaining the quotes?

```
?- print('4x').
'4x'
true.

?- print([a,b,'4X',d]).
[a,b,'4X',d]
true.
```

Of note: [portray/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=portray/1)

I have never used `portray/1` but you might.